# Symfony swiftmailer send multiple mails inside loop

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I need to send multiple mails with symfony swiftmailer inside a loop. This is my code.

```
public function __construct($name = null, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, EngineInterface $templating) {
        parent::__construct($name)
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->templating = $templating;
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
  foreach ($ads as $ad) {
                if($counter == 10) break;
                $this->sendMail($ad->getUser()->getMail(), $ad, 'matching');
                $counter++;
  }
}

protected function sendMail($mail, $ad, $template = '') {

        if($template == 'matching'){
            $template = 'emails/matching-cars.html.twig';
        }elseif($template == 'owner'){
            $template = 'emails/matching-car-owners.html.twig';
        }

        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
                ->setFrom('admin@admin.com')
                ->setTo($mail)
                ->setBody(
                $this->templating->render(
                        $template, [
                            'ad' => $ad
                        ]
                ), 'text/html'
        );

        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
```

Since I'm doing it inside loop it's really hard to pass mails array to swift mailer. I'm running this inside [Console Command](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html) and I'm getting this error in console.

> 17:14:09 ERROR     [app] Exception occurred while flushing email
>   queue: Expected response code 354 but got code "550", with message
>   "550 5.7.0 Requested action not taken: too many emails per second

Comment: You can use the `Throttler Plugin` exemples in the [documentation](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/plugins.html)

Answer (score 0):

### symfony swiftmailer send multiple mails inside loop

let assume you have function called sendEmail that you use to sent email to all users that have account in you system.

Here are explanation that can help you to solve email error with code implementation:

For me it work....

```
  public function sendEmail(\Swift_Mailer $mailer): Response
            {    
                     $entityManager=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                     $connection= $entityManager->getConnection();
                     $decl12="SELECT id
                        FROM
                         user";
                    $statement97=$connection->prepare($decl12);
                    $statement97->execute();
                    $tap=$statement97->fetchAll();
        
            try{
               foreach($tap as $i=>$data)
               {
            //check what type of data taken from variable data by
            //var_dump($data);    
 $test =$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['id'=>$data]);                                                                   
                $email=$test->getEmail();
       
                                    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Email Subject'))
                                        ->setFrom('admin@gmail.com')
                                        ->setTo($email)
                                        ->setBody(
                                            "click here to get bonus",
                                            'text/html'
                                        );
                                   $mailer->send($message);
                  }
               } 
        catch (\Swift_TransportException $e) 
            {
             return new Response($e->getMessage());
             }
        
      }
```